# AWS Cloudformation output double quotes in a file using Fn::Join

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

After much research and frustration, I'm not quite getting the output I'm hoping for.

The desired output into a file would be for example

```
"accessKeyId":"UIIUHO]SOMEKEY[SHPIUIUHIU"
```

But what I'm getting is

```
accessKeyId:UIIUHO]SOMEKEY[SHPIUIUHIU
```

Below is the line in an AWS Cloudformation template

```
{"Fn::Join": ["", ["echo \" accessKeyId:", {"Ref": "AccessKeyId"}, "\" >>  /home/ubuntu/myfile.json"] ] },
```

I've tried adding \" with in the echo statement but no quotes are output.  Can someone show how to produce the desired output above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a problem of correctly escaping the quotes in fact.

Reason is : `\"` inside a CloudFormation string is escaped as `"` (double-quote).

For example, `"hello \"me\""` gives you :

```
hello "me"
```

In your line, what you really feed to bash is :

```
echo " accessKeyId:XXXXX" >> /home/ubuntu/myfile.json
```

Considering bash use of quotes, you get the string

```
accessKeyId:XXXXX
```

inside your `/home/ubuntu/myfile.json`

To solve your problem, I would recommend using:

```
{"Fn::Join": ["", ["echo '\"accessKeyId\":\"", {"Ref": "AccessKeyId"}, "\"' >>  /home/ubuntu/myfile.json"] ] },
```

which is escaped as

```
echo '"accessKeyId":"XXXXX"' >>  /home/ubuntu/myfile.json
```

(hard to read : the whole string used by echo is inside single-quotes).

I'm not able to try it now, but it should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you! That first and last single quote did it.

Comment: Escaping and encoding have been created to give full-time jobs to IT guys! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to generate a file on the EC2 instance being started by CloudFormation, I would recommend the following approach :

In the "Resources" section (adapt your policy accordingly):

```
     "User": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::User",
            "Properties": {
                "Path": "/",
                "Policies": [
                    {
                        "PolicyName": "AllPrivileges",
                        "PolicyDocument": {
                            "Statement": [
                                {
                                    "Effect": "Allow",
                                    "Action": [
                                        "*"
                                    ],
                                    "Resource": [ "*" ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
    },
    "AccessKey" : {
       "Type" : "AWS::IAM::AccessKey",
       "Properties" : {
          "UserName" : { "Ref" : "User" }
       }
    },
```

In the EC2 Instance resource section :

```
        "Metadata" : {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
              "config" : {
                    "files" : {
                      "/home/ec2-user/.aws/config" : {
                        "content" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                          "[profile eb-cli]", "\n",
                          "aws_access_key_id = ", { "Ref" : "AccessKey" }, "\n",
                          "aws_secret_access_key = ", { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "AccessKey", "SecretAccessKey" ] }, "\n"
                        ]]},
                        "mode" : "000600",
                        "owner" : "ec2-user",
                        "group" : "ec2-user"
                      }
                    },
```

Adding double quotes in the output should be as simple as escaping them such as

```
          "files" : {
                      "/home/ec2-user/.aws/config" : {
                        "content" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                          "[profile eb-cli]", "\n",
                          "\"aws_access_key_id\" = \"", { "Ref" : "AccessKey" }, "\"", "\n",
                          "\"aws_secret_access_key\" = \"", { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "AccessKey", "SecretAccessKey" ] }, , "\"", "\n"
                        ]]},
                        "mode" : "000600",
                        "owner" : "ec2-user",
                        "group" : "ec2-user"
                      }
                    },
```

But this is not required for AWS CLI and SDK configuration files

In order to trigger the `AWS::Cloudformation::Init` section of your template, you must explicitly call `cfn-init`

I am usually doing this from the user data section :

```
            "UserData" : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                "#!/bin/bash -x\n",
                "exec &> /home/ec2-user/userdata.log\n",
                "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, " -s ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackId" }, " -r DockerInstance -v\n",
                "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? ", { "Fn::Base64" : { "Ref" : "WaitConditionHandle" }}, "\n"
            ]] } }
```

Comment: Hi Sébastien, my favorite AWS trainer ! Hope to see you again one day, maybe in Rennes (France) again?! Jean-Marc

Comment: :-) maybe ! Did my answer help you ?

Comment: Thanks Sébastien!  Your answer did help. The files I have should be written as you've outlined.  I'll be looking at this method moving forward.

Comment: I edited my answer to add a reference to cfn-init.  If the answer looks correct, do not hesitate to accept it :-)