# Cloudformation echo json env variable

Tags: json, regex, bash, escaping, aws-cloudformation

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307976/aws-cloudformation-output-double-quotes-in-a-file-using-fnjoin/27334419#27334419), where I am running into issues with putting JSON into a file. The issue is, no matter how I've formatted my strings inside the userData section of the CloudFormation template, I can't seem to capture an env $variable while maintaining a valid JSON object (with double quotes around the keys and values)

Below are two different ways I've tried to get the object into a file (via `echo` and `cat << EOF < env-config.json`) with virtually every combination of string escaping (single quotes wrapped around double quotes escaped around object keys...etc..)

```
echo '{\"development\": {\"EnvironmentConfig\": {\"api\": \" 'http://$ip:8000/api' \"}}}' >> env-config.json\n"

 

cat << EOF > env-config.json
{\"development\": {\"EnvironmentConfig\": {\"api\": \" 'http://$ip:8000/api' \"}}}
EOF
```

How can I place my perfectly formatted JSON object into a file while capturing an env $variable in it from the userData section of CloudFormation?

Thank you!

**edit**

**Tools involved: gulp-ng-config, bash, cloudformation, json**

Using gulp-ng-config to create a module with constants with the env-config.json file

Comment: How would you like to _exactly_ output the `JSON` ?

Comment: {"development": {"EnvironmentConfig": {"api": "http://$ip:8000/api" }}}
 where $ip is the env variable. @Inian

Comment: Can you see my answer is what you need?

Comment: hi @Inian I'm reviewing your answer now. I actually kept working on it and found out this worked (remember this is from cloudformation so there are double quotes " " around the whole command) : `echo '{\"development\": {\"EnvironmentConfig\": {\"api\": \"'http://$ip:8000/api'\"}}}' >> env-config.json\ `

Comment: @Inian as I mentioned in the op, I had been escaping my double quotes as needed. if I hadn't been, cloudformation would not have ran my template. So I cannot accept your answer although I greatly appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer, I needed single quotes around the url portion (as well as the double quotes) of my JSON like the below. This is what the whole line would look like in Cloudformation, I hope this helps someone:

```
"echo '{\"development\": {\"EnvironmentConfig\": {\"api\": \"'http://$ip:8000/api'\"}}}' >> env-config.json\n",
```