# CloudFormation Userdata to Base64 Decoding Incorrectly

Tags: powershell, unicode, base64, aws-cloudformation

I've created a CloudFormation template that creates an instance. I want to pass a PowerShell script into a windows instance via the user data; however, when it's encoded with Base64, the Cloudformation template does not decode it correctly.

I want to pass in this:

`Set-DNSClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex (Get-NetAdapter).InterfaceIndex -ServerAddresses ("172.31.15.30")`

When I check the template in the CloudFormation it got decoded as:

`Set-DNSClientServerAddress /u2013InterfaceIndex (Get-NetAdapter).InterfaceIndex /u2013ServerAddresses ("172.31.15.30")`

When this is passed into the Windows instance, it doesn't recognize `/u2013`, and errors out.

How do I ensure the line I pass in keeps the dash, rather than decode it into Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

```
Could you try this?

"Set-DNSClientServerAddress \-InterfaceIndex (Get-NetAdapter).InterfaceIndex \-ServerAddresses ("172.31.15.30")"
```

Based on others needing to escape other characters: [AWS Cloudformation output double quotes in a file using Fn::Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307976/aws-cloudformation-output-double-quotes-in-a-file-using-fnjoin)

Answer (score 0):

`\u2013` is a different type of [unicode dash character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm). Your editor probably used it because it looks nicer. Try editing your source code with notepad or a simple editor and replace that unicode dash with a proper dash. If you are having a hard time typing it, you can copy it from `Set-DNSClientServerAddress`. That one seems fine.